# Rowwise summation

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a question regarding rowwise summation when using na.rm. I have the following dataset

```
CombData <- data.frame(WC=c(rep(NA, 4)), 
           NCO=c(rep(NA,4)), 
           FIN=c(-304.583,-275.356,-286.75,-223.596), 
           TACC=c(rep(NA,4)))
```

My code looks like this:

```
CombData <- CombData %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(TACC = sum(WC + NCO + FIN, na.rm = TRUE))
```

What I actually want is:

```
data.frame(WC=c(rep(NA, 4)),
           NCO=c(rep(NA,4)), 
           FIN=c(-304.583,-275.356,-286.75,-223.596), 
           TACC=c(-304.583,-275.356,-286.75,-223.596))
```

Why does my code not yield the result above?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can just do `df %>%
 mutate(TACC = rowSums(select(., WC, NCO, FIN), na.rm = TRUE))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are already using `sum` so no need to add `+` in there :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(TACC = sum(WC,NCO ,FIN, na.rm = TRUE))

#  WC    NCO     FIN  TACC
#  <lgl> <lgl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 NA    NA    -305. -305.
#2 NA    NA    -275. -275.
#3 NA    NA    -287. -287.
#4 NA    NA    -224. -224.
```

However, a simpler option exist in base R:

```
rowSums(df, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Without using `dplyr`, you can do

```
CombData$TACC <- rowSums(CombData, na.rm = TRUE)
```

but if you want to use `dplyr`, you can do

```
CombData %>% 
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(TACC = sum(WC, NCO, FIN, na.rm = TRUE))
```

Answer (score 0):

With `tidyverse`, we can also use `pmap`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
CombData %>%
      mutate(TACC = pmap_dbl(., ~ sum(c(...), na.rm = TRUE)))
```